# А зачем использовать push и pop для дополнительного регистра?

Tags: ассемблер

А зачем использовать `push` и `pop` для дополнительного регистра? И без них все получается правильно

```
power:
push %ecx
mov %eax, %ecx
loop:
dec %edx
test %edx, %edx
jz after
imul %ecx, %eax
jmp loop
after:
pop %ecx
ret
```

Comment: Видимо ваш компилятор старается сохранять значение регистра ecx. Тогда функция, которая вызывает power, может не волноваться, что ecx после вызова функции может быть изменён.

Comment: Скорее всего тут используется какое-то нестандартное соглашение вызова: например, процедура не должна использовать никакие регистры кроме тех, через которые ей передаются значения аргументов (eax, edx в данном случае). "Без них все получается" - получается только до тех пор, пока вызывающий код полагаясь на соглашение вызова не положит что-то важное в ecx, и процедура это значение не затрет.